# How to Create Case in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 (Version 8) using webservices or REST API in JAVA or C#?

Tags: java, c#, rest, web-services, dynamics-crm

I want to create a case in Microsoft Dynamics 2018(Ver.8) using either C# or java using web services.
After doing a vast googling I'm having hard luck with no or very few resources that are hardly useful. The Microsoft documentation is a complete dead end.
Following are my requirements:

1. Creating a CASE.
2. Updating CASE more likely closing of CASE.
3. Creating a CONTACT.

I need to perform these actions using Rest API or Webservice either in JAVA or C#.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Are you familiar with Dynamics CRM SDK? or REST API?

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with REST API, and regarding Dynamics CRM SDK no, I've just started going through the reference links  from @RedCrusador

Comment: Can you show us that what you have tried so far? and what kind of issue you are experiencing?

Comment: Hi Yayub, with respect to MS documentation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg328291(v=crm.8) I'm working on the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are non on-prem, your data will reside in the Common Data Service (CDS).

So perhaps the reason why you can't find anything is because you are searching specifically for connecting to Dynamics.

There is full developer guide here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/work-with-data-cds

A sample POST request is below to create a entity - in this case ACCOUNT (be it a CASE or CONTACT you will need to ensure you have the right attributes corresponding to your entities).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/create-entity-web-api

For some code ready examples see below. I would suggest starting with a simple WebAPI connection, then using this as a base to contruct the operations you wish to complete.

https://github.com/microsoft/PowerApps-Samples/tree/master/cds/webapi/C%23/SimpleWebApi

Your best to stick to C# as there will be more examples around the web. But you can use any language you wish that has the abilty to create and post a request to the endpoint so JAVA can be used as well.

Comment: Quick question before I dig in the given resources, will they work for Microsoft Dynamics 2016 (ver 8). Also, the instance is on-premises.

Comment: The reference is based on the latest version. There are subtle differences between versions, they used to be additive. Now breaking changes have been released between V8 and V9. But the demo should still work with on-prem V8 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/web-api-versions

Comment: Hi RedCrusador, 
After deep digging into the ms documentation, if found following relevant context,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg328291(v=crm.8)
here they have mentioned the required input fields.
I do have a doubt, regarding why they are asking for redirect URI. Any help would be appreciated.